# Tensorflow operation on non-zero vectors

Tags: python, tensorflow

I have spent about two hours on this, but could not find the solution. The closes thing to what I need is probably this [boolen mask](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/boolean_mask), but I am still missing the next step.

My neural network wasn't learning so I started looking at every step it performs. And sure enough I found a problem. The problem lies in the fact that due to sparsity on my input layer I get too many bias terms propagated throughout. Uniqueness of my set up though is that the last `time` matrices will be zero matrices. Let me show you, I will first show a screenshot of my notebook and will then present the code.

screenshot:

[image]

I do not want bias terms added to where the whole `time` is a zeros matrix. I thought I could perhaps perform an op on the boolean mask filtered matrix?

Here is the code:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

dim = 4
# batch x time x events x dim
tensor = np.random.rand(1, 3, 4, dim)
zeros_last_time = np.zeros((4, dim))
tensor[0][2] = zeros_last_time

input_layer = tf.placeholder(tf.float64, shape=(None, None, 4, dim))

# These are supposed to perform operations on the non-zero times
Wn = tf.Variable(
    tf.truncated_normal(dtype=dtype, shape=(dim,), mean=0, stddev=0.01),
    name="Wn")
bn = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal(dtype=dtype, shape=(1,), mean=0, 
stddev=0.01), name="bn")

# this is the op I want to be performed only on non-zero times
op = tf.einsum('bted,d->bte', input_layer, Wn) + bn

s = tf.Session()
glob_vars = tf.global_variables_initializer()
s.run(glob_vars)

# first let's see what the bias term is
s.run(bn, feed_dict={input_layer: tensor})

s.run(op, feed_dict={input_layer: tensor})
```

EDIT: So I believe `tf.where` is what I need.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a good solution can be the usage of `tf.where` to create a mask of zeros where the input is zero (in the last dimension) and is one otherwise.
Once we got this mask, we can just multiply it for the bias to get the result.
Here's my solution:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

dim = 4
# batch x time x events x dim
tensor = np.random.rand(1, 3, 4, dim)
zeros_last_time = np.zeros((4, dim))
tensor[0][2] = zeros_last_time
dtype = tf.float64
input_layer = tf.placeholder(tf.float64, shape=(None, None, 4, dim))

# These are supposed to perform operations on the non-zero times
Wn = tf.Variable(
    tf.truncated_normal(dtype=dtype, shape=(dim,), mean=0, stddev=0.01),
    name="Wn")
bn = tf.Variable(
    tf.truncated_normal(dtype=dtype, shape=(1,), mean=0, stddev=0.01),
    name="bn")

bias = bn * tf.cast(
    tf.where(input_layer == tf.zeros(tf.shape(input_layer)[-1]),
             tf.zeros(tf.shape(input_layer)[-1]),
             tf.ones(tf.shape(input_layer)[-1])), dtype)

# this is the op I want to be performed only on non-zero times
op = tf.einsum('bted,d->bte', input_layer, Wn) + bias

s = tf.Session()
glob_vars = tf.global_variables_initializer()
s.run(glob_vars)

# first let's see what the bias term is
print(s.run(bn, feed_dict={input_layer: tensor}))
print(s.run(op, feed_dict={input_layer: tensor}))
```

Comment: I found this `tf.where` just when you posted the answer. I assume you are still writing up the answer? Because the above is just the copy of the code I provided :)

Comment: getting this error when running the above:
```Incompatible shapes: [1,3,4] vs. [3,4,4]```

Comment: Ahhrg! Sorry again, I pasted again another test. Update with the correct version (I just executed it, so this one should be the good one)

Comment: I still have bias in the final `time` :)

Comment: the zeros one should be this: `tf.zeros(tf.shape(input_layer)[2:])`

Comment: in fact that first statement in `tf.where` only returns either `True` or `False`, but we actually need a vector of `True`/`False` for each `time`

Comment: so this is the first part of what I need:

`tf.equal(input_layer, tf.cast(tf.zeros(tf.shape(input_layer)[2:]), tf.float64))`

Comment: and then this `tf.where(zeros, tf.zeros(tf.shape(input_layer)), tf.ones(tf.shape(input_layer)))`. But I also need to have `bn` there instead of ones, but it has to be of the right shape. So almost done

Answer (score 0):

I managed to get the right bias, but then noticed that the dimensions are messed up. So this is only a partial answer:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

dim = 4
# batch x time x events x dim
tensor = np.random.rand(1, 3, 4, dim)
zeros_last_time = np.zeros((4, dim))
tensor[0][2] = zeros_last_time

dtype = tf.float64
input_layer = tf.placeholder(dtype, shape=(None, None, 4, dim))

# These are supposed to perform operations on the non-zero times
Wn = tf.Variable(
tf.truncated_normal(dtype=dtype, shape=(dim,), mean=0, stddev=0.01),
name="Wn")
bn = tf.Variable(
tf.truncated_normal(dtype=dtype, shape=(1,), mean=0, stddev=0.01),
name="bn")
zeros = tf.equal(input_layer, tf.cast(tf.zeros(tf.shape(input_layer)[2:]), 
tf.float64))

# bias
where_ = tf.where(zeros, tf.zeros(tf.shape(input_layer)), 
tf.ones(tf.shape(input_layer)))

bias = bn * tf.cast(where_, tf.float64)

op = tf.einsum('bted,d->bte', input_layer, Wn) + bias  # will fail

print(bias)
s = tf.Session()
glob_vars = tf.global_variables_initializer()
s.run(glob_vars)
s = tf.Session()
glob_vars = tf.global_variables_initializer()
s.run(glob_vars)
feed_dict = {input_layer: tensor}
s.run(bias, feed_dict)
```

and these two for bias do the job:

`biases = tf.slice(biases, [0, 0, 0, 0], [1, 3, 1, 4])
squeezed_biases = tf.squeeze(biases)`